# Chroot средствами htaccess или php ini

Tags: php

Задача: при манипуляциях с файлами, чтобы `/` трактовалась как

```
/var/www/blah-blah-blah/mysite.ru/www
```

Только добиться этого разом для всего проекта. Реально?
Всякие

```
define('BASEDIR',dirname(__FILE__));
```

знаю, но не то.

Comment: htaccess вроде как тут совсем непричем, а про такое не слышал даже)

Comment: Насколько понимаю, php такую работу передает сразу ОС и с другой стороны тут не подступиться. Поковырял слегка сурсы php, я так понимаю, за открытие файлов отвечает [эта функция](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/Zend/zend.c#L454), которая действует "напрямую". Так что, видимо, только chroot.

Comment: А чем `define('BASEDIR',dirname(__FILE__));` не понравилось?

Comment: @Pavel Volyntsev иногда на поддержку попадают проекты, которые писались "под сервак" и прямо на серваке.

Comment: 1. Укажи root в настройках домена Apache или nginx, хотя не уверен
2. В настройках текущего пользователя unix можно заменить root, но тогда под разные проекты нужно разных пользователей в системе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй [jail на linux](http://www.webnext.ru/blog/2007/07/07/jail-chroot.html) - по ссылке инструкция под Gentoo, могу дать ссылки под другие версии.

Через chroot конкретному пользователю заменяешь root, копируешь в его домашнюю папку в поддиректорию /usr/bin нужные программы (php)

Запускаешь веб-сервер от имени этого пользователя

Если нужно для нескольких проектов, то поменяй пользователя в настройках веб-сервера и перезапусти.

Вообще это геморой при большом количестве проектов. При определённом их количестве ты подумаешь, что будет проще определить константу BASEDIR, как у тебя указано, и везде по проекту заменить '/' на BASEDIR

Comment: В общем, это ответ. Спасибо, буду старыми проверенными средствами.